# CakePHP pretty URL's not working on production server

Tags: apache, cakephp, vhosts

I have developed a CakePHP application that I have now deployed to my production server, however pretty URLs do not work.

Here is my Apache vhost for the site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName site.com
    ServerAdmin support@site.com

    DocumentRoot /home/whitey/sites/site.com/htdocs/app/webroot/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/whitey/sites/site.com/htdocs/app/webroot/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/whitey/sites/site.com/logs/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /home/whitey/sites/site.com/logs/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see, the document root is set to the `webroot` directory in my app. Inside that directory, there is this .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This entire setup works perfectly with my local machine running XAMPP, so I'm not sure what's wrong. The only thing I can think of is the rewrite rules aren't taking effect because of a setting in my vhost. But I haven't got enough knowledge of the Apache config files to know how to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I forgot to enable the mod_rewrite module for Apache when I set it up last night. Here's the fix:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```